# Why am I getting a ValueError in the provided?

Tags: python-3.x, valueerror, wiener-filter

I am trying to create a Wiener filter and check for filter values from 2 to 20. I get 18 graphs as required but I keep getting an error even though I get an output. I know my code is not the cleanest and I only started Python a few months ago as Lockdown project. Any and all help will be appreciated. The code is written according to formulae provided in the question.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy import linalg
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io as sio
N = 109068
data = sio.loadmat('audiodata.mat')
y = data['audio']
y = np.reshape(y,(109068,1))
v2 = data['noise']
v2 = np.reshape(v2,(109068,1))

for t in range(1,18):
    for n in range (t+1,20):
        rv2 = np.zeros(t+1)
        ryv2 = np.zeros(t+1)
        rv2[t] += 1/(n-t)*v2[n]*v2[n-t]
        ryv2[t] += 1/(n-t)*y[n]*v2[n-t]
        Rv2 = sp.linalg.toeplitz(rv2)
        Rv_2 = sp.linalg.inv(Rv2)
        w_opt = np.matmul(Rv_2,ryv2)
        v1 = sp.signal.lfilter(w_opt,1,v2)
        y_filt = y-v1
        ts = np.arange(0.,  y.shape[0]/22050, 1/22050)
        fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3,sharex=True,figsize=(15,10))
        ax1.plot(ts, y,'b')
        ax1.plot(ts, y_filt,'g')
        ax2.plot(ts, v1)
        ax2.plot(ts, v2)
        ax3.plot(ts, y_filt)
        plt.xlabel('Time[s]')
        plt.ylabel('PCM')
        plt.show
```

The error is get is this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-244-7a0d629580e8> in <module>
     19         ryv2[t] += 1/(n-t)*y[n]*v2[n-t]
     20         Rv2 = sp.linalg.toeplitz(rv2)
---> 21         Rv_2 = sp.linalg.inv(Rv2)
     22         w_opt = np.matmul(Rv_2,ryv2)
     23         v1 = sp.signal.lfilter(w_opt,1,v2)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\basic.py in inv(a, overwrite_a, check_finite)
    972         inv_a, info = getri(lu, piv, lwork=lwork, overwrite_lu=1)
    973     if info > 0:
--> 974         raise LinAlgError("singular matrix")
    975     if info < 0:
    976         raise ValueError('illegal value in %d-th argument of internal '

LinAlgError: singular matrix
```

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the mistake. I just needed another for loop above t to correctly iterate for t itself.